# How to get all elements of ArrayList exactly once in java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

If i have an ArrayList that contains "Cat" "Cat" "Dog" "Bee" "Dog" "Cat".

How can i then produce an array that contains each element exactly once in java?

I want to end up having the following array:

"Cat" "Dog" "Bee"

Comment: Use a Set instead of an ArrayList.  It's called "the right tool for the job."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Set` for this:-

```
Set<String> uniqueElements = new HashSet<String>(myList);
```

This `Set` will now have all the Elements of your `ArrayList` but without **duplicates**.

Comment: Thx for all the replies. I used the above example - works good :)

Answer (score 2):

You should add the elements to a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which by definition requires the elements to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

`Set` contains unique elements:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

Then convert it to `array`:

```
String[] array = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```